# How to get the IP Address from the views or middleware to the models?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

Since few hours ago I am facing a basic problem sod I have decided to ask a question after tried to do many many example but I still have an error.

my answer is that I want to put the user's country according to his ip address for the registration or other queries.

I mean the ip address will be collected from a view function with or my middleware file.

I want to do like this but I want to get the ip address from my view or my middleware as I said it.

This is my function to get the ip address from my view or my middleware file:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
       ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    return ip
```

So once I got the ip address let's say from my view how can I get this ip address to my models to do this process below?

this is what I expected for:

```
ip = '0.0.0.0'
readerone = GeoIP2()
readerone.country_name(ip)
visitor_info = readerone.city(ip)
dma_code = visitor_info['dma_code']
city = visitor_info['city']
continent_code = visitor_info['continent_code']
continent_name = visitor_info['continent_name']
country_code = visitor_info['country_code']
country = visitor_info['country_name']
latitude = visitor_info['latitude']
longitude = visitor_info['longitude']
postal_code = visitor_info['postal_code']
region = visitor_info['region']
time_zone = visitor_info['time_zone']

current_country = country
```

So when I got the country by the ip address I can pass it into my default country like this into my models:

```
class GetSomeInfoByIp(models.Model):

    city  = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', null=True, 
    blank=True)
    ip_address  = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=120, 
    choices=COUNTRIES, default=current_country)
    state_or_department  = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Why can't you save that data in the same way you save full_name etc?

Comment: Please show your view code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a global variable problem into django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462420/how-to-fix-a-global-variable-problem-into-django-model)

Comment: Hello @DanielRoseman sorry but the fullname doesn't matter, the most important is to get the ip address to from my middleware or my views to my models.

Comment: Hello @IvanStarostin is another question for anoter problem but the both are similar.

Comment: Rephrasing the title does not make this question different. You're still struggling on saving ip into your model. And still showing no code.

Comment: Yes the full name was just an example, the point is that you are presumably already setting that somewhere, so it's not clear why you are struggling to do the same with the IP.

Comment: Hello @IvanStarostin the views code is the ip address function and you have the model and what process a want to do it. Is there any solution to get the ip address collected from the ip address function into my views to my models ? this is my question. Thank you.

Comment: No, that function is not the view.

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes is it, because I do it separately the ip address function.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you might not understand but is there any kind of solution to get this ip address from my views function to my models ? this is the only problem I have and the only problem I really need fix. Thank you.

Comment: As with your previous question there is **absolutely no way to answer this** because you refuse to show any code. Of course it is possible. **When you create the model instance in your view you should just pass it the IP along with the rest of the data**. I don't understand what you are finding difficult here.

Comment: Hum, I don't really know why you gars said that you don't understand my question and said that I didn't show a code. Hum, I just give an example for what I really want to do, into my question, I said that to select a default country according to the user ip address like this country = models.CharField(max_length=120, 
    choices=COUNTRIES, default=current_country) and this is what I want to do before save the data to the database.

Comment: and the current_country is what I got from the ip address before it save when the user visited my web site.

Comment: Hello to @DanielRoseman and IvanStarostin  I just want you know that I resolved my problem by myself. and my solution does exactly what I was expected for! So I am so happy. Thanks you gars.

Comment: @Michael if you solved the problem yourself you should be able to post the solution you found as an answer.